# How can I create a poll on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I have seen polls on Facebook. I even remember creating them. However, I can no-longer find how to do it. What do I need to press?

What I tried:

- Click home
- Click to edit new post
- Click ... to select type of post
- Stop, as I don't see poll.

Comment: Have you seen [this help page](https://www.facebook.com/help/1575289455869004)?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Facebook Group Poll Option]
Maybe Facebook removed the poll option from. News Profile Home & Pages You can still create normal polls in Your Groups Go to [name] group. Write something. Swipe up for options>Poll [I am assuming you are using Facebook App]

### Alternative

You can still create a YES/NO poll from your profile home & page..But I needs to be on a image

Wtite post > Select image from Photo/Video > next > edit > click the sticker icon > POLL > write your question [You can set values for YES/NO > Done > Post

Comment: Try Facebook Group

Comment: I managed to do a poll in a group. I now wonder how I can share it to other groups. I could not workout the alternative.

Comment: The Poll need to be in privacy Public..Share like normal. Alternative- add picture, click edit, add poll, done, post. This allows only 2 options